C++ STL: how does std::unordered set and std::unordered_map hashing work?
I am trying to understand how STL unordered set/map (i.e. hash maps) work.
I understood that initial hash table size (i.e. number of buckets) is set to 8 and when more elements are added to the set/map this number will be doubled again and again.
So, AFAIU set/map should keep an array of buckets.
I understand that the default hash function used (say, for int) is:
size_t std::hash<int>(int key);

By definition, hash function maps key to index in the hash table, i.e. to the index of the bucket in the array of buckets.
So the hash function needs to map any int key to the index from 0 to size of the buckets array.
However, the hash function does not receive the buckets array size, so how does it know it?
Same if I provide my own hash function which will receive only the key, e.g.:
struct HashFunctionCalc
{
  size_t operator()(int key) const { return ... }
};

How will it know to map this key to the index of the bucket without knowing how many buckets there are?
Thanks in advance...

There'll be an internal mapping from the hash to buckets inside the map

This is not a question about STL, this is rather a more generic question about data structures and algorithms.

If the std::size_t hash; value is going into one of 42 buckets, it'll use bucket[hash % 42].  The hash value itself does not need to be constrained to the range 0 .. 41.

OK, seems I understand now.
Hash table used in STL (unordered_map, unordered_set) is not a classic hash table with a constant pre-defined size where the hash function returns the position in the table.
The STL hash table is a variable size (or more precisely, adjustable size) hash table. And so, the hash function does not have access to the number of buckets, and so it should be generic: i.e. it should try to map the keys uniformly for any possible number of buckets. Hash function of the STL hash table returns not the index in the table, but a hash value which will be converted into bucket index by:
bucketIndex = hashValue % numOfBuckets.


I understood that initial hash table size (i.e. number of buckets) is set to 8 and when more elements are added to the set/map this number will be doubled again and again.

The C++ Standard doesn't dictate an initial size, nor a ratio by which resizing should be done.  You can observe the behaviour of your own implementation by calling the .bucket_count() function as you do operations on a container.  Some implementations, such as GCC and Clang, use prime-number bucket counts, so definitely won't start at 8 and double.  MS Visual C++ does use power-of-two bucket counts though, so while I'm not sure what size it takes on when you've just added one element, it very likely uses doubling after that.

So, AFAIU set/map should keep an array of buckets.

unordered_set/unordered_map, yes.

By definition, hash function maps key to index in the hash table, i.e. to the index of the bucket in the array of buckets.


So the hash function needs to map any int key to the index from 0 to size of the buckets array. However, the hash function does not receive the buckets array size, so how does it know it?

As Elijay pointed out in a comment, this doesn't need to be done directly - the needs to the unordered containers can be met by 1) a hash function that outputs any size_t values, and 2) a function that "folds" size_t values over the current buckets.  So if we have hash_value = hash_function(key) return a size_t, then we can apply bucket_index = hash_value % bucket_count() to identify a bucket.  Iff the hash table implementation is using power-of-two bucket counts, then a masking operation can be used: hash_value & (bucket_count() - 1) - this is of interest because a % mod operation takes most CPUs quite a long time to calculate (e.g. 40-60 CPU cycles on various x86 family CPUs from the last decade), whereas subtraction and bitwise-AND operations are trivial to calculate and will each complete in 1 CPU cycle.
If you really want to get good performance out of hash tables, it's important to keep these factors in mind when you select/write a hash function.  For example, if you have an identity hash function (i.e. hash_value == key) for double*s, which due to alignment tend to be multiples of 8, then an implementation using power-of-two bucket counts will typically slice off the low order bits of the hash value (that's what % and bitwise-AND do), and in this case the three least-significant bits will all be 0s, so only every eighth bucket will be used, leading to a ~8x more collisions than wanted.  Implementations using prime-number bucket counts are much less prone to this kind of problem, but can't use the bitwise-AND optimisation.
